# how fix Authorization Bearer Problem in guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm trying to send this request to the server, but with a 401 error
Which part of the code can the problem be?

"guzzle version 6.3"

```
try {
        $urlDoPayment = 'https://api.example.com/v1/pay';
        $client = new Client();
        try {
            $response = $client->request('POST', $urlDoPayment, [
                \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
                    'form_params' => [
                        'amount' => 100,
                        'returnUrl' => "https://example.com/payment/verify",
                        'payerIdentity' => "",
                        'payerName' => "",
                        'description' => "",
                        'clientRefId' => ""
                    ],
                    'headers' => [
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
                        'Accept' => 'application/json'
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $content = $response->getBody();
            dd($content);
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        dd($exception->getCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved using this code

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $urlDoPayment, [
                'json' => [
                    'amount' => 100,
                    'returnUrl' => "http://example.com/payment/verify",
                    'payerIdentity' => "",
                    'payerName' => "",
                    'description' => "",
                    'clientRefId' => ""
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
                    'Accept' => 'application/json'
                ]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `headers` in the request are nested in the wrong part of the request options. That should at least fix the 401 error if the token is valid.

Try:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', $urlDoPayment, [
    \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
        'form_params' => [
            'amount' => 100,
            'returnUrl' => "https://example.com/payment/verify",
            'payerIdentity' => "",
            'payerName' => "",
            'description' => "",
            'clientRefId' => ""
        ],
        // headers should not be here
    ], // json post body params end
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem lays in undefined port or protocol. Headers content wasn't an issue for me. I resolved same problem by changing:

`115.12.3.44` to `115.12.3.44:80`

also tested

`115.12.3.44` to `http://115.12.3.44`

or

`google.com` to `http://google.com`